# DNS Errors through VPN Connection

Tags: windows, windows-8.1, vpn, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a DirectAccess server on Windows Server 2012 R2. It is working well for most of my clients. I have one client (Windows 8.1), however, which has an old group policy on it with the wrong IP-HTTPS URL, and therefore it cannot connect to the DirectAccess server. I need to somehow update the group policy on this computer so it can get the correct new settings, but unfortunately it is on the other side of the continent and I can't just hook it up to the internal network and update the policy. So, I have been trying to get it connected over a VPN to update the policy that way.

I have tried connecting it both with a PPTP VPN (the system built-in to Remote Access in Windows Server 2012 R2) and also through OpenVPN. I am having the same problem with both of them. Running `GPUpdate` returns the error

> The processing of Group Policy failed because of lack of network connectivity to a domain controller.

So apparently even with a VPN connection, it can't access the domain controller. I am rather confused with this because I can ping the IP address of the domain controller, but the FQDN will not resolve. For example, if the ActiveDirectory/DomainControl server is at `DomainControl.mynetwork.local` with IP address `10.198.0.2`, I can run `ping 10.198.0.2` fine but running `ping DomainControl.mynetwork.local` or just `ping DomainControl` from the client returns the error

> Ping request could not find host DomainControl.mynetwork.local. Please
>   check the name and try again

Interestingly, if I try `nslookup DomainControl.mynetwork.local` it returns the correct address `10.198.0.2`.

In summary, I cannot seem to update the group policy because the domain controller's FQDN will not resolve on a VPN client (and apparently GPUpdate uses FQDN instead of IP address to access the domain controller?). This does not seem to be a DNS issue over the VPN because nslookup can resolve it fine. I have no idea what to do next.

**EDIT:** To help narrow down where the issue is occurring, I set up a Wireshark capture to examine the DNS requests. With `nslookup` it all looks good, but when I try a `ping` it doesn't even send out a DNS request. Looks like for some reason it's not even attempting to look it up from the DNS server. Also, pinging an external server while connected through the VPN (e.g. `ping www.google.com`) returns a valid response.

**EDIT #2**: Some more experimenting with Wireshark shows the following, which might help with debugging:

- `ping DomainControl` does not send any request
- `ping DomainControl.` sends a NBNS/NetBIOS request that returns "requested name does not exist"
- `ping DomainControl.mynetwork` sends a DNS request that returns "no such name"
- `ping DomainControl.mynetwork.` sends the same as previous
- `ping DomainControl.mynetwork.loca` sends a DNS request that returns "no such name"
- `ping DomainControl.mynetwork.local` does not send any request
- `ping DomainControl.mynetwork.local.` does not send any request

Comment: Can you post a complete `ipconfig /all` from the client while connected to the VPN?